# What is the better way to generate test report in a file using BOOST.Test?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I know by default report is directed to standard-error, and so one has to redirect it to a file.
My question is shall we do this inside a global fixture? Which isn't seem to be working for me some how.

This is what i tried -

```
struct MyConfig
{
 MyConfig()
  : testReport("fileName.log")
  {
    if(!testReport.fail())
     original = std::cerr.rdbuf(testReport.rdbuf());
  }
  ~MyConfig()
    {        
        cerr.rdbuf(original);        
        testReport.close();
    }
    ofstream testReport;
    streambuf* original;

 };

 BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(MyConfig);
```

After running the test, report outputs on console only, though a 0kb file is created with the given name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this alternative, adapted from [here](http://bitten.edgewall.org/wiki/BoostTest) and alleged to work on Boost 1.34.1. This seems to be more as Boost intends - see the usage of a results stream overrider.

```
//
// run_tests.cc
//

#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/results_reporter.hpp>

std::ofstream ReportRedirector::out;

struct ReportRedirector
{
    ReportRedirector()
    {
        out.open("fileName.log");
        assert( out.is_open() );
        boost::unit_test::results_reporter::set_stream(out);
    }
private:
    static std::ofstream out;
};

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(ReportRedirector)
```

Comment: why `out` needs to be declared as `static`?

Comment: I don't see any reason why non-static would fail here, but this is the version that was supposed to have been tested, per the info in the link.

Answer (score 5):

With Boost 1.44.0 (and maybe later versions) you need the following code to create a global fixture which redirects the output of the test program to a file named after the master testsuite in which the test is included (see [Boost Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-output/log-ct-config.html))

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

struct LogToFile
{
    LogToFile()
    {
        std::string logFileName(boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite().p_name);
        logFileName.append(".xml");
        logFile.open(logFileName.c_str());
        boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.set_stream(logFile);
    }
    ~LogToFile()
    {
        boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.test_finish();
        logFile.close();
        boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.set_stream(std::cout);
    }
    std::ofstream logFile;
};

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(LogToFile);
```

In this example `logFile` is not a static member like in the answer provided by [Steve Townsend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786639/what-is-the-better-way-to-generate-test-report-in-a-file-using-boost-test/3788021#3788021) because declaring `logFile` as static member resulted in wrongly generated XML and accessing the fixture struct is not thread-safe this way.

<strike>However, there seems to be a bug in Boost 1.44.0 which also results in incorrect XML output getting generated if `logFile` is not a static member of the fixture struct (probably the same bug I mentioned before).
To fix this the line `logFile << "</TestLog>" << std::flush;` is needed before closing the filestream in the destructor to generate valid XML.</strike>
Thanks to @Wracky (comment below) I replaced the line `logFile << "</TestLog>" << std::flush;` with `boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.test_finish();` which is a much cleaner solution than writing the tag manually.

**NOTE:** the tests are run with the following parameters:  `--output_format=XML --log_level=all --report_level=no`.
This enables the usage of the resulting XML files with the [xUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) for the [continuous integration server Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: This doesn't work with reports unfortunately.  I require the command line "--report_format=XML --report_level=detailed" to work with QuickBuild but none of the output appears in the xml file.

Comment: I had the same problem with the last </TestLog> tag not being there. I figured, since it's my own output stream, I have to tell boost that the test is over some how. And it appears there is such a function.

If I add this:
`unit_test_log.test_finish();`
to the code, just before I close the logfile, I do get the </TestLog> tag in my output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Wracky. I'll definitly try this and update the answer if it works for me.

Answer (score 5):

For Completeness:

You don't have to redirect the input yourself if you don't want to.
You can also specify a logfile via command line arguments:

```
C:\MyTest.exe --log_sink=fileName.log
```

Took me a while to find. Hope this helps!

Comment: for someone starting out using the Boost unit testing framework, this is a easy to set up simple crude test report method, without needing to understand the specifics of the logging commands. +1